# Display titles above each printed table

Tags: java, html, jsp

I need your assistant and help in solving the issue while displaying the records in a table. I am looking for a group header to be placed above each printed table for its related category and subcategory, as well as, the no. of the records for each table to be shown at the top of the table.

The table contains columns for category, subcategory, name. ex:

`Category    Subcategory     Name`

`CON         Retail          AAA`

`CON         Wholesale       BBB`

`SPEC        Retail          CCC`

What I am looking for is the below layout:

Category/Subcategory (No. of records) –similar to a group header

Name – Country ..etc ----Table header

table records

Here is my code below:

```
<%
//Retrieve the values from the DB
while (rs.next())
{
    category_name1=rs.getString("category_name");
    subcategory_name1=rs.getString("subcategory_name");
    //to compare the existing category with the previous one and to display group header
    if ((category_name1).equals(temp_category_name) ) {
        category_name1="";
%>
<%=category_name1%> / <%=subcategory_name1%> <%=count%>  //Currently it is showing duplicate values many times and the count is wrong
<%
}
if (!(subcategory_name1).equals(temp_subcategory_name)) {
    count=0;
%>
<table width="80%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th>Country </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<%
}
%>
    <tbody>
<%
    name=rs.getString("name");
    country_name=rs.getString("country_name");
    temp_category_name=category_name1;
    temp_subcategory_name=subcategory_name1;
    count++;
%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=i%></td>
            <td><%=institution_name%></td>
            <td><%=country_name%></td>                                            
        </tr>
<%
}
%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem in the above code is that it is showing the group headers category & sub catgeory multiple times and the count is incorrect. So, please assist me in correcting the above one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at This code:

```
    if ((category_name1).equals(temp_category_name) )
    {
       category_name1="";  ///HERE IS YOUR PROBLEM!!!
    }
    ....
    ....
    temp_category_name=category_name1; ///PROBLEM ABOVE MESSES THIS UP.
```

Setting `category_name1` to empty string when its equal to the last category, and then setting the last category for the next iteration to `category_name1` which is now empty string, ensures that if the category occurs more than twice, the name is going to get printed again.   Instead of setting `category_name1` to empty string you could use an if-statement to print it as an empty string but leave the real value in the variable.

There are other problems with this code, but this is the main one.  Also, someone on here will inevitably tell you "Don't use scriptlets, use JSTL."

As for the record count.  The way you're doing it, you would have to display the record count at the ***end*** of the category, not the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you mean I should keep at the beginning of the if statement ! and it will solve the issue? One more thing, regarding the count, how to display the total at the top?

Comment: You'd have to count first then print the heading. As it stands, you are printing the heading first, then counting.

Comment: Still I need more details please for both of the issues